# What does the phrase "all sharing two common strands" imply?

Tags: phrases, expressions

The image says:

> "There are several Khasi tournaments played through the year, in all villages, all sharing two common strands - the prize goat and that all players are tribal people."

I don't quite understand the meaning of *"all sharing two common strands"*

[The image is a part of the cover story of a national daily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCyUI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a figurative use of the word *strand*: just like multiple (fiber) strands make up a thread,  multiple strands (factors/subplots) may make up a whole (concept/plot).

> "There are several Khasi tournaments played through the year, in all
>   villages, ***all unified by two common factors*** [all sharing two common strands] - the prize goat and that all
>   players are tribal people."

ODO:

> **[strand](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/strand)**[2]
>   *NOUN*
>   **1.3** An element that forms part of a complex whole.
>
> ‘He never adequately connects the several different strands he's
>   weaving into a cohesive whole theory.’